# Is it possible to fetch the title of a web page using selenium after clicking the print button?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I need to **validate the title** of a web page which is **changing after clicking the print button**. But after clicking the button the **page title is changing** and also **it is opening the print preview** window which is out of scope for selenium. Is there any way to get the title of that page?

I have tried **driver.getTitle()** but that is not working in the print preview page.

Comment: It may not be working because the active window is the print preview window since you clicked on it. Have you thought about switching back window handlers so that the active is back on the main web page?

Comment: Code attempts for how you _tried driver.getTitle()_ which _is not working_?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using getTitle(), try the below:

```
WebElement title = driver.findElement(By.tagName("title"));
System.out.println(title.getText());
```